# Windows Form BindingSource to LinqToSql fails to apply the 'Filter' property

Tags: linq, filter, objectdatasource, bindingsource

I'm building a Windows Forms application and on many of these forms I use a BindingSource that is linked to a LinqToSql object. I also have a DataGridView which uses the BindingSource. This works really nice and all the create/edit/update work.

However when I put in a string in the Filter property like this:

```
VesID='ABC'
```

it doesn't filter.  Is there a special syntax that I need to make the filter work with an object datasource?

Comment: I'm curious myself.  I have never gotten the `BindingSource.Filter` to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the binding source's `SupportsFiltering`?
I bet it's `false` because LINQ doesn't support dynamic queries out of the box.

Why do you want dynamic queries anyway? LINQ is all about type safety and you really should use its built-in filtering with `Where`:

```
var query = db.Customers.Where(x => x.VesID == "ABC");
grid.DataSource = query;
```

If you really *do* need to specify a string filter condition (which is *rarely* the case), have a look at two libraries: [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: Sure enough! - SupportsFiltering was `false` - didn't realise that these properties existed `... SupportsSearching, SupportsSorting ...` - thanks for the tip - and your right, it's probably wise to stick with Ling for filtering